flet and closures?
I defined a local recursive function using flet.  The recursive function calculates factorials:
 (flet ((my-fac (n)
           (cond ((= n 1) 1)
                 (t (* n (my-fac (1- n)))))))

Then I used mapcar to apply my-fac to each element of a list to produce a list of factorials:
(defun my-mapping (lst x)
  (flet ((my-fac (n)
           (cond ((= n 1) 1)
                 (t (* n (my-fac (1- n)))))))
    (mapcar #'my-fac lst)))

Note the unused second parameter variable in the my-mapping definition.  Here are the results:
CL-USER> (my-mapping '(1 2 3 4) 1)
(1 2 6 24)

Next, I changed the my-mapping function to use the second parameter variable:
(defun my-mapping (lst x)
  (flet ((my-fac (n)
           (cond ((= n 1) x) ; <==========CHANGE HERE
                 (t (* n (my-fac (1- n)))))))
    (mapcar #'my-fac lst)))

As a result of the change, I expected when I called (my-mapping '(1 2 3 4) 2), the results would be factorials that were multiplied by 2.  Therefore, instead of getting the previous result:
  (1 2 6 24)

I expected to get:
  (2 4 12 48)

Here are my actual results
CL-USER> (my-mapping '(1 2 3 4) 2) 
(2 2 6 24)

It looks to me like my-fac picked up the value for x when calculating the factorial for 1 (the first element in the list), but for the rest of the elements in the list it looks like x had a value of 1 somehow.

There are two ways to define local functions: FLET and LABELS.
See the CL Hyperspec for the specification of FLET and LABELS.
It says about FLET:

The scope of the name binding encompasses only the body. Within the
body of flet, function-names matching those defined by flet refer to
the locally defined functions rather than to the global function
definitions of the same name.

It says about LABELS:

labels is equivalent to flet except that the scope of the defined
function names for labels encompasses the function definitions
themselves as well as the body.

Means:
(flet ((my-local-function ()
         ...))  ; <- my-local-function CAN'T be used here

  ; my-local-function can be used in the body:
  (my-local-function))

(labels ((my-local-function ()
         ...))  ; <- my-local-function can be used here

  ; my-local-function can be used in the body :
  (my-local-function))

LABELS is used for recursive functions.
Here you are using FLET, which won't work.
(defun my-mapping (lst x)
  (flet ((my-fac (n)
           (cond ((= n 1) x) 
                 (t (* n (my-fac (1- n)))))))  ; <- problem
    (mapcar #'my-fac lst)))                    ; <- no problem

In above function the recursive call to MY-FAC is not possible. FLET does not allow self-recursive calls. You are calling a global function called MY-FAC. You would need to have such a function, to make above code work. I would suspect that this is the case, defined in prior experiments.
To actually call the local recursive function replace FLET with LABELS:
CL-USER 16 > (defun my-mapping (lst x)
               (labels ((my-fac (n)
                          (cond ((= n 1) x)
                                (t (* n (my-fac (1- n)))))))
                 (mapcar #'my-fac lst)))
MY-MAPPING

CL-USER 17 > (my-mapping '(1 2 3 4) 2)
(2 4 12 48)

Above shows that one gets the expected result.
The problematic code and the Lisp compiler
This is for example what the LispWorks compiler says:
CL-USER 18 > (defun my-mapping (lst x)
               (flet ((my-fac (n)
                        (cond ((= n 1) 1)
                              (t (* n (my-fac (1- n)))))))
                 (mapcar #'my-fac lst)))
MY-MAPPING

CL-USER 19 > (compile *)
;;;*** Warning in MY-MAPPING: X is bound but not referenced

The following function is undefined:
MY-FAC which is referenced by MY-MAPPING

SBCL says:
; in: DEFUN MY-MAPPING
;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA MY-MAPPING
;         (LST X)
;       (BLOCK MY-MAPPING
;         (FLET ((MY-FAC #
;                  #))
;           (MAPCAR #'MY-FAC LST))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable X is defined but never used.
; in: DEFUN MY-MAPPING
;     (MY-FAC (1- N))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::MY-FAC
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     MY-FAC
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions


You are calling a global function called MY-FAC. You would need to have such a function, to make above code work. -- I tested out my-fac as a global function to make sure it worked before using flet to define my-fac.  Even though I commented out the global my-fac, it must still have been loaded into the slime repl.  About the unused parameter variable, I must have gotten that warning the first time I compiled the function, but the second, third, etc. time I compiled the function, I did not get that warning.  When I restarted the slime repl and compiled again, I got the  warning again.

I read the hyperspec on flet and labels, and I couldn't make any sense of the text.   Add in my mistake with the globally defined my-fac, and I could not understand the results.  After restarting the repl, I now see: undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::MY-FAC. Thanks!

@7stud : that's strange, the compiler would usually complain each time.

@stud: I've added quotes from the Hyperspec, where the difference is explained.

I tried duplicating the state where I was not seeing the The variable X is defined but never used  with this function: (defun add (x y)  y), but I couldn't do it: I got the warning no matter what I tried.  I find that slime often gets out of sync with my code: either issuing a warning/error when I know the code is correct after changing it, and then when I run my code it works without error; or I'll get no warnings/errors when compiling with C-c C-c and then when I run my code I get errors.  As a result, I don't really trust what the slime repl  tells me.

@7stud: that sounds unusual. The only thing I can imagine is that C-c C-c does not compile the piece you want to compile. When in doubt compile the whole buffer: select all code, do m-x Compile Region. Or: save the file and do C-c C-k , which does Compile/Load File.

Yes.  When I'm having problems, e.g. I know my code is correct but I still get warnings/errors, I often switch between C-c C-c and C-x C-s then C-c C-k.  I didn't use C-c C-k during this session however.  I'll keep that in mind the next time I see things getting out of sync between the slime repl and my code.  I'm using emacs 29.1, SBCL 2.4.0, slime 2.29.1.
